# Error correction : Our soldiers were better trained than that of enemies

Tags: exam-questions

> Our soldiers (a)/ were better trained (b)/ than that (c)/ of enemies. (D)

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise. A friend of mine suggested to me to change *that* to *those*  in part C but isn't the part D also wrong? I guess it should be possessive of *enemies* that ie either *enemy's* or *enemies*'.

Comment: The original sentence seems to have multiple errors.  I would write "...than *those of the enemy*" or "...than the enemy's", but both of those involve multiple changes.  If the exercise said there could be multiple errors, then that's OK, I guess.

Comment: ***that*** refers to *[the] **soldiers** [of enemies]* - which is plural, so it should indeed be plural *Our soldiers were better trained than **those** of enemies*. Idiomatically, almost all native speakers would include some kind of "determiner" before ***enemies*** (I'd usually expect ***our** enemies*), and only full context would establish whether the plural is acceptable (I'd usually expect *...than those of our/the **enemy***). To be honest, I suspect your example question text was set by a non-native speaker. The possessive apostrophe is completely inappropriate with *that / those of*.

Comment: It would be **enemys'** not **enemy's** because **of [our] enemies** is plural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about such a sentence: _Our soldiers were better trained than the ones of the enemies'_ ? Does an apostrophe fit in here?

Comment: @WeatherVane  for correct spelling it must be either *enemies'* or *enemy's*, depending on whether there are many or one enemy. But as noted by FumbleFingers this doesn't look like a question set by a native speaker.

Comment: @JamesK yes my slip: **enemies'**

Answer (score 1):

The correct form would be:

> Our soldiers were better trained than those of the enemies.

But I think it would be more natural to say:

> Our soldiers were better trained than our enemies'.

Comment: Assuming multiple enemies.

Answer (score 0):

As we can not determine how many enemies (one enemy or a few enemies), part D should be considered correct grammatically.

Because there are a few soldiers, so part C is incorrect because it's not in plural form.